# Jenkins, Git and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, jenkins

I'm new to Jenkins and experimenting at the moment. I use Eclipse and run Git from within Eclipse, using the Git plugin, which is described as follows: 'Eclipse Git is an Eclipse Team provider based on JGit, a pure Java implementation of the Git version control system'.

I've installed the Git plugin for Jenkins but when I go to configure it, Jenkins complains that it can't find the Git executable. That makes sense, and the obvious solution is to install it (in my case, using a Ubuntu repository - *sudo apt-get install git-core*). My concern is that having two installations of Git on the machine will give rise to problems - or am I being over-cautious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine to have both - since EGit is pure Java, it has nothing to do with the installed (native code) version of Git.

Problems might arise if there was a breaking change in a future version of Git, but it should be easy enough to fix by updating both installations.