# EGit and post-commit hook

Tags: eclipse, git, hook

This is a follow-on to my question at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226287/jenkins-git-and-eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232026/egit-hooks-do-not-get-triggered)

I'm trying to get a post-commit hook running which will invoke a Jenkins build. I can create the hook, place it in my native Git (i.e. not EGit) *hooks* directory and it works as intended. However, I prefer to have the hook running in my EGit environment as I don't want the complexity of managing two Git environments. I cannot, however, establish where I should place the hook in order for it to be picked up by EGit - any ideas?

=================

Answering my own question - seems EGit cannot do this - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226287/jenkins-git-and-eclipse)

Comment: If you want to answer your own question, please do so a a *real* answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to have a commit start a jenkins build, then just configure the jenkins job to poll the git repository and start a build whenever a change (=new commit) is found.